# If height is higher then 400px use another css line instead?

Tags: javascript, php

I was wondering if there was an If statement that could do the following :

```
<div style="min-height:400px;">
some dynamic content
</div>
```

The if statement or function would be something like

```
<?php
    if height is higher then 600 px change class from A to B or change Css lines like f.e. smaller font size
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the div in the DOM and check it's height; toggleClass allows you to pass a string separated by a space and it will flip between the two classes when invoked.

```
//css
.cls1{}
.cls2{}

//html
<div id="iamunique" class="cls1">
    some dynamic content
</div>

//js
<script>
    var $div = $('#iamunique');
    if ($div.height() > 600) $div.toggleClass('cls1 cls2');
</script>
```

Comment: You've got a syntax error. It should be `if ($div.height() > 600)`. Can't edit 1 char myself..

Comment: @Joaquín O - thanks for spotting that, change made.

Comment: thank you very much, helped a lot :)